# IE cannot interpret my flash player because of a question mark, but every other browser can

Tags: php, flash, internet-explorer

Hey guys, I have another really annoying problem in IE. I am using a php mp3 handler script that I use as a parameter, but it seems to mess everything up just because there is a question mark after .php for my get variables. If I remove the question mark (mp3_handler.php?), the player appears, but with the question mark, it shows up as a text box. **The first player works fine. The second just appears as a textbox in IE.** The second however works in every other browser!!!

**UPDATE:** IT SEEMS TO BE THE second QUESTION MARK, but I do not see a way around this..   Oddly enough, the first question mark does not make a difference

```
    <object width="165" height="37" id="niftyPlayer1" align="">
    <param name=movie value="nifty/niftyplayer.swf?file=song.mp3&as=0">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name=quality value=high>
    <param name=bgcolor value=#FFFFFF>
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <embed src="nifty/niftyplayer.swf?file=song.mp3&as=0" quality=high bgcolor=#FFFFFF width="165" height="37" name="niftyPlayer1" align="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" swLiveConnect="true" wmode="transparent">
    </embed>
    </object>

    <object width="165" height="37" id="niftyPlayer1" align="">
    <param name=movie value="niftyplayer.swf?file=mp3_handler.php?ID=4cf3c07080533cb52ed86631d5aea6af&t=1&topic_id=a3b68d08198628e25c64eb3ad223dfb8&as=1">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name=quality value=high>
    <param name=bgcolor value=#FFFFFF>
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <embed src="nifty/niftyplayer.swf?file=mp3_handler.php?ID=4cf3c07080533cb52ed86631d5aea6af&t=1&topic_id=a3b68d08198628e25c64eb3ad223dfb8" quality=high bgcolor=#FFFFFF width="165" height="37" name="niftyPlayer1" align="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" swLiveConnect="true" wmode="transparent">
</embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Without seeing your server, it's tough to know, but I'm guessing you don't have your mp3_handler.php does not set the mime type correctly. IE is much stricter than the rest of the browsers about handling MIME types.

Comment: it does header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');

Comment: the problem seems to be the question mark after mp3_handler.php? when I remove that, then it stops being a text box and turns into an mp3 player, the thing is, I need those get variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work (`urlencode()ing` the value):

```
niftyplayer.swf?file=mp3_handler.php%3FID%3D4cf3c07080533cb52ed86631d5aea6af%26t%3D1%26topic_id%3Da3b68d08198628e25c64eb3ad223dfb8%26as%3D1
```

I'm not sure which GET variable should go to swf & which to mp3_handler.php, but you get the idea.

Comment: I was just looking at urlencoding lol, but I was not sure what value was the proper one. That did work, thanks Wrikken, appreciate it.

Comment: It's technically not legal to have more than one question mark in a URL. IE was, for once, following the standards. When one url (mp3_handler.php and company) is a parameter in another url (niftyplayer.swf and company) then it must be url-encoded so that it's clear which value is part of which URL.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Comment: luis I am not exactly sure how this helps me

Comment: SWFObject is a standardized way to automatically generate the proper HTML for a given browser.  You should consider using it, regardless of whether or not it solves your current problem.

Comment: SWFObject is an easy-to-use and -->standards-friendly<-- method to embed Flash content, which utilizes one small JavaScript file

Comment: You should use SWFObject.  Let me repeat that: use SWFObject.

Comment: isn't that a lot of trouble for something that can be fixed with much less code? I am just curious on why you guys see this as such a valued addition to your arsenal of tools. Also, can I maintain my player and attribute integrity through this plugin?

Comment: how could my example be served through this? I am already serving the swf source through nifty.js